# angular-chart js time on x Axis is not comes in fraction

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

using 
 angular 1.6.4
 angular-chart 1.1.1
 ChartJS 2.6.0

below is my dataset format

`[{num_records_1: 0, num_records_2: 0, timestamp: 1498715881917}, {}]`

there comes 24 hours data with every 2 hours span, `timestamp` key has time in milliseconds 
I set X axis type "*time*" and below  is my settings for the graph taken from this [Refrence](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-cartesian-axis)

```
var timeSetting = {
                unit: 'hour',
                displayFormats: {
                      'minute': 'kk:mm',
                      'hour': 'kk:mm'
                },
                tooltipFormat: 'MMM D, HH:mm A',
                unitStepSize: 2
            };

vm.line.options.scales.xAxes[0].type = "time";
vm.line.options.scales.xAxes[0].time = timeSetting;
```

But on graph , it display 3 hours span on X axis ticks like *11:00 2:00 5:00* whereas timestamp has the value in *11:04 1:04 3:04* and so on

what I require is the X axis ticks will point the exact time which I have in dataset ?

what is missing here, kindly help and guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you told the chart that the xAxes was type "time", the tick text will not be based on the data point values.  It will be based on the minimum and maximum dates in the whole dataset, as well the other time properties being set.  The actual data point times should show up in tooltips.  If you want the minutes to show up in the ticks, change the unit to 'minute'.  Given you description, that will be too many ticks for your data.  But when you specify the unit as 'hour', the ticks will only be on and exact hour boundary with zero minutes.  The number of hours (units) between ticks should be handled by setting unitStepSize.  I do not see why you would be getting 3 hour intervals.  Are there more option settings that might affect that?  Like maxTicksLimit?

Comment: so if I change `unit: 'minutes'` and `'unitStepSize': 120` than does it works?Yes I have other configuration  `xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                autoSkip: false,
                                stepSize: 1,
                                maxRotation: 0
                            }`

Comment: That should get the ticks to show minutes values, at 2 hour intervals, but unless you add a min setting, where that 2 hours starts is going to be picked by the library.  With a time axes, I do not know of any way to make sure that the ticks shown are the same time values at the data.  It might work if the data is really every 2 hours, and the min tick is set to the min data time.  Not sure how that stepSize will mix with the unitStepSize.  Can you put up a jsfiddle, or similar with a sample?

Comment: I have  configureed with `{min:dataset[0].timestamp, max: dataset[dataset.length-1].timestamp}` than it display the start and end point exact but middile of ticks are again on fix hours ( like 2:00, 4:00). I will create the fiddle very soon. data is really coming after every 2 hours.